# Why can't Darktable see my image folder?

Tags: filesystems, directory

I recently added a new SSD hard drive to my machine (the specs of the machine [are here](https://joereddington.github.io/2023/07/05/pc.html) to use for my photography.  I mapped the hard drive (this is on ubuntu) to the /archive folder and everything has been working entirely normal until I try and import with darktable.

My folder listing looks like this:

[image]

But Darktable can only see these folders:

[image]

which are subtly different.

Indeed, when I click 'other locations' I see this:

[image]

Which suggests that there is a special 8Gb computer I'm looking at, rather than my actual disk.

What is happening here and how can I get Darktable to notice /Archive as a folder?

Answer (score 1):

This was migrated before I could accept one of the answers but:

Darktable is installed with snap, which sandboxed it to only be able to access folders in my home directory - I changed the SSD drive mount to be the home directory to solve the problem (although I suspect that there are more elegant solutions)

Comment: (For avoidance of doubt - there were no answers when this question was migrated, only comments)

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yeah - I phrased that terribly.

Answer (score 1):

Completely different answer...

Shun the distro's snap and install from [the developers site](https://www.darktable.org/install/). No restrictions, and a more recent/capable version.You can either

- [add a repo to your sources](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=graphics:darktable&package=darktable), and install like the rest (and get automtic updates)
- [download the .DEB](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=graphics:darktable&package=darktable) and do a speficif install.

Note: despite being on an OpenSuse site, you will find instructions for Ubuntu.